# ¿Cómo hacer click en este botón?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventos, dom

Tengo un problema que no logro resolver. Basicamente se trata de que no se puede hacer click en un botón después de anpendizarlo aunque exista. El problema se puede resumir con este código verifiable dónde `$('#btn_hidden').click();` no funciona aunque el elemento exista.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{        
    class HidennButton
    {
        constructor()
        {
            this.appendHiddenButton();
            this.click();
        }

        appendHiddenButton()
        {
            var txt ="";
            txt += '<button type="button" id="btn_hidden" style="display:none">Hide</button>';      
            $('body').append(txt);
        }

        click()
        {       
            $('#btn_hidden').click();
        }

        removeHiddenButton()
        {
            $('#btn_hidden').remove();
        }
    };


txt ="";
txt += '<button type="button" id="start">Start</button>';
$('body').append(txt);


hb=null;

$("#start").click(function() 
{   
    //el problema se da únicamente cuando se crea el objeto
    //dentro del evento "onClick" del botón "start"
    hb = new HidennButton();
});

$("#btn_hidden").click(function() 
{   
    hb.removeHiddenButton();
});


});
```

Decir también que si el objeto se crea fuera del evento "onClick" del botón "start", si se se puede hacer click en él botón oculto (pero así pierde toda la útilidad que yo pretendo darle al código).

También he intentado esperar por el elemento haciendo esto.

```
function rafAsync() 
{
    return new Promise(resolve => 
    {
        requestAnimationFrame(resolve); //faster than set time out
    });
}   

async function checkElement(selector) 
{
    while (document.querySelector(selector) === null) 
    {
        await rafAsync();
    }
    return true;
}  
    click()
    {       
        checkElement("#" + this.mssg_id) 
        .then((element) => 
        {
            console.info(element);
            $('#btn_hidden').click();                       
        });

    }
```

Pero a pesar de que la función "checkElement()" parece funcionar bien `$('#btn_hidden').click();` sigue sin funcionar.

¿Alguna idea para solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casi lo tienes, sólo hay un par de cosas (o una sola cosa en dos pasos) que se deberían cambiar para que funcione:

1. **Usa eventos delegados**: cuando se ejecuta el siguiente código para asignar un controlador al evento `click` de `#btn_hidden`, no existe aún ningún elemento que cumpla con el selector:

   ```
   $("#btn_hidden").click(function() 
   {   
       hb.removeHiddenButton();
   });
   ```

   Como el botón `#btn_hidden` aún no existe (se debe pulsar en Start para que se cree), esa asociación de evento se va a ejecutar, y no se va a asociar a nada. Por lo que cuando hagas click en `#btn_hidden` no ocurrirá nada porque realmente no se le asoció ningún controlador del evento click.

   La solución sería usar [eventos delegados](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), que permiten asociar eventos a elementos que aún no se han creado y no existen en el documento. Algo como esto:

   ```
   $("body").on("click", "#btn_hidden", function() 
   {   
       hb.removeHiddenButton();
   });
   ```

Pero ahora surge un segundo problema: cuando pulsas en el botón, da un error en la consola diciendo que `hb` no está definido. Esto ocurre porque en el constructor de la clase se está llamando al método `click` que ahora sí se lanza... pero en ese momento, aún no existe `hb` porque está en mitad del proceso de creación y aún no se ha devuelto. Para solucionar esto:

2. **Espera a que el objeto esté preparado antes de interactuar con él**. Me puedes echar la culpa a mí de esto, por cómo hice lo de arriba. Pero la solución también es fácil: quita el `this.click` del constructor, y pon un `hb.click` justo después de su definición.

Puede no ser muy bonito, pero funciona:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  class HidennButton {
    constructor() {
      this.appendHiddenButton();
    }

    appendHiddenButton() {
      var txt = "";
      txt += '<button type="button" id="btn_hidden" style="display: none;">Hide</button>';
      $('body').append(txt);
    }

    click() {
      $('#btn_hidden').click();
    }

    removeHiddenButton() {
      $('#btn_hidden').remove();
    }
  };


  txt = "";
  txt += '<button type="button" id="start">Start</button>';
  $('body').append(txt);

  hb = null;


  $("#start").click(function() {
    //el problema se da únicamente cuando se crea el objeto
    //dentro del evento "onClick" del botón "start"
    hb = new HidennButton();
    hb.click();
  });

  $("body").on("click", "#btn_hidden", function() {
    hb.removeHiddenButton();
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Es perfercto!! Muchas gracias por la ayuda y por la respuesta tan elaborada @AlvaroMontoro!!